# Make strip of nan in a matrice matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have an image size `(m x n x 4)` I want to make strip of `0` or `NaN`on it. I want the strips to be 4 pixels wide and having a space of about 30 pixels between them. That is when I display the image in `RGB` I have strips of `NaN`. Can somebody help me out with this, please?

Comment: Can't you just address them, like `var(x:y, xx:yy, xxx:yyy) = nan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted you question as "how can I repeatedly draw black lines with a given width and a specified offset over an image".

```
img = imread('peppers.png');
height = size(img,1);
strip_width = 4;
strip_offset = 30;

line_start_idx = 0:(strip_width+strip_offset):height;
line_idx = ndgrid(line_start_idx,1:strip_width)';
line_idx = line_idx(:);
line_add = repmat(1:strip_width,1,length(line_start_idx))';
line_idx = line_idx + line_add;

img(line_idx,:,:) = 0;
imshow(img)
```

[image: image with black lines drawn repeatedly]